# Append path to sudo secure_path

Tags: path, append, sudo

I am trying to append a path like say /usr/local/ssh in /etc/sudoers.d/path to /etc/sudoers which already has:

Defaults secure_path="/usr/bin:/sbin"

How can I append another path to secure_path in /etc/sudoers.d/path without changing the default sudoers. If I put in the new file this, then it overrides the default secure_path in sudoers.:

Defaults secure_path="/usr/bin:/sbin"

Comment: This doesn't work: 
Defaults secure_path+="<some new path>"

Comment: `+=` doesn't work either. Having the line overwrites the original `secure_path` completely, and I see no way of referring to the original `secure_path`